# Android:Changing time format as per the Device's Current time format

Tags: android, time, android-widget

How to get current time format of the android device? i.e. If the android device's current time format is changed from 12hr to 24 hr format and vice versa, then how to check that setting programatically?

I want to change the time shown in my app widget to be of same format as the device's and whenever the time format is changed then my widget should also show that time format. Any pointers will be helpful.

thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [TIME_12_24](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html#TIME_12_24).

```
int time_format = 0;
try {
    time_format = Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.TIME_12_24);
} catch (SettingNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Log.i(TAG,"Time format: "+time_format);
```

`time_format` will have *12* or *24* based on the settings.

Make sure you have added this permission to manifiest file.

```
<user-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```

**EDIT :**
You can also use [DateFormat.is24HourFormat()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html#is24HourFormat(android.content.Context)).  It doesn't require an extra permission.

Answer (score 3):

The simple way would be to use to use android native `android.text.format.DateFormat` class's `is24HourFormat(this)` static method as below.

```
if (android.text.format.DateFormat.is24HourFormat(YourActivityName.this)) {
          // 24 hour format
}
else
{
    // 12 hour format
}
```

Answer (score 1):

check, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html

`DateFormat::getDateFormat()`

```
Date date = new Date(location.getTime());
dateFormat.format(date);
```